# Including the namespace property when Serializing using Microsoft-Avro-Core

Tags: json, serialization, namespaces, schema, avro

I am serializing C# objects to an avro file format using the Microsoft-Avro-Core nuget package. The issue I am having is that the avro schema contains a namespace property in the json schema definition, which is not included in the schema of the serialized avro file.

ex.

```
{
  "name": "typeName",
  "type": [
    {
      "type": "record",
      "name": "recordName",
      "namespace": "topLevelRecord.record_data",
      "fields": [
      ]
    },
    "null"
  ]
}
```

after serializeing, to avro, the containing schema definition is written without the namespace like so:

```
{
  "name": "typeName",
  "type": [
    {
      "type": "record",
      "name": "recordName",
      "fields": [
      ]
    },
    "null"
  ]
}
```

This is creating an issue for us since the consuming code no longer contains the namespace. How can I tell the serializer to include the namespace property in the serialized avro file.

Setting the Name and Namespace properties of the DataContract attribute does not work. It simply prefixes the serialized name property with the namespace. Which is not what we need.

We are using the SequentialWriter to serialize a collection of records. The AvroSerializationSettings object does not contain a property to enforce the serialization of the namespace.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some research, it turns out the RecordSchema serializer doesn't include the namespace. After reviewing the code on github, it uses the FullName property as the name and leaves out the namespace.

[Microsoft.Avro-Core](https://github.com/welly87/Microsoft-Avro-Core/blob/4fcab4e9274c4176ab5879a2502801ee9982ce78/src/Microsoft.Hadoop.Avro/Schema/RecordSchema.cs#L117)

We did not define the schema. But we have to use it. In order to be compliant the serialized schema must include the namespace.